# Can a term have multiple parents from different vocabularies?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-6, custom-taxonomy, drupal-taxonomy

Is it possible in Drupal Taxonomy?
I've many pages related to consumer products to be in following vocabularies:

1. Electronics
2. Washing maching
3. TV
4. Mobile
5. Cars
6. Electrical

... all sorts of

Now Sony TV would go in **TV** and also in **Electronics**.
Is it possible to do it in Taxonomy ie to inherit from multiple parents which belong to different vocabularies.

Comment: No, I don't think so. But why don't you create a single voculabary and allow to select multiple terms of that, if necessary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The drupal taxonomy system is not created to have terms that overlap each other. That would mess up the hierarchal order that terms are used for.

In your example, TV should be a child of Electrical, since all TV's are electrical.

Comment: In my country, TV is considered an electronics item. That is, Sony is in Electronics business. Simply what I want to ask is whether a term can have parents from different vocabularies.

Answer (score 2):

Drupal 6 permits to set multiple term parents.

Adding multiple parents to a term will cause the segemntacaoTeste vocabulary to look for multiple parents on every term. Because multiple parents are not supported when using the drag and drop outline interface, drag and drop will be disabled if you enable this option. If you choose to have multiple parents, you will only be able to set parents by using the term edit form.

You may re-enable the drag and drop interface at any time by reducing multiple parents to a single parent for the terms in this vocabulary.

Answer (score 1):

it is better to use other fields, e.g external Id, or rtid for referring to different vocabularies as compared to having multiple parents per term.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure, that author of this issue has found his answer, but in case if someone else still looking for such solution, this seems to be good start.
http://drupal.org/project/term_relations

I'm not sure how mature this solution is for D7, but if we want to avoid custom module creation, this should be best start.